# Adding displayName to new Firebase Auth profile upon register submission in React app

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I have created a 'register' component in my React web app which successfully registers users upon submission.

During that flow, I am attempting to set the 'displayName' too with a '.then' call.

This for whatever reason though isn't working. I'm attempting to follow the documentation, but no luck unfortunately.

Would somebody be able to point out what I'm doing wrong?

Here's my component:

```
class Register extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      displayName: "",
      email: "",
      password: ""
    }
  }

  onChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value})
    }

  onSubmit = async (e) => {

    e.preventDefault()

    await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
      .then(function(result) {

        console.log(result);
        console.log("Successfully created new user.")
        return result.user.updateProfile({
          displayName: this.state.displayName
        })

      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
      });

      this.props.history.push("/dashboard")

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <section className="register-section">

          <form className="register-form" onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>

            <label className="register-label">Full Name</label>
            <input className="register-input" type="text" name="displayName" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.displayName} />
            <label className="register-label">Email</label>
            <input className="register-input" type="email" name="email" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.email} />
            <label className="register-label">Password</label>
            <input className="register-input" type="password" name="password" onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.password} />
            <button className="register-button" type="submit" name="button">Continue</button>

            <a className="register-link" href="sign-in">Got an account already?</a>
          </form>

        </div>
      </section>
    )
  }
}

export default Register;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: Here's the solved code.

```
  onSubmit = async(e) => {

      e.preventDefault()

      await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
        .then(() => {
          console.log("Successfully created new user.")
          console.log(this.state.displayName)
          let firebaseUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
          return firebaseUser.updateProfile({
            displayName: this.state.displayName
            })
          })
        .catch((error) => {
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode);
          console.log(errorMessage);
        });

      this.props.history.push("/dashboard")

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the current user from firebase and then call the *updateProfile()* method on this user.

```js
onSubmit = async(e) => {

  e.preventDefault()

  await firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(this.state.email, this.state.password)
    .then(function() {
      console.log("Successfully created new user.")
      let firebaseUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      return firebaseUser.updateProfile({
        displayName: this.state.displayName
      })

    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode);
      console.log(errorMessage);
    });

  this.props.history.push("/dashboard")

}
```

Comment: I feel the logic to this is correct, but it doesn't work unfortunately. The user is successfully created, but the displayName isn't updated.

Comment: Are you sure there's a value in the state for displayName? Did you "console.log(this.state.displayName)" ?

Comment: You're right - I added a console log in the 'then' function and it's coming through as undefined. I've done some playing this morning and discovered it's to do with the structure of the 'then'. I learned this elsewhere, but you need an arrow function to access 'this.state'. Your answer is right except for that. I'll edit my answer to show you what I mean.